# How to extend an enumeration type?

Tags: delphi, enums, delphi-xe7

I often need to add a "default value" to some third party enumeration types, for example:

```
  TThirdPartyEnum = (
    eA,
    eB,
    eC
  );
```

I would like to define an enumeration type like this:

```
TMyEnum = (
  eA,
  eB,
  eC,
  eDefault
);
```

I would like to refer to the `TThirdPartyEnum` values in order to avoid maintainance of `TMyEnum` (Which should be updated each time `TThirdPartyEnum` values changes).

I've unsuccessfully tried as follows:

```
  TMyEnum = Low(TThirdPartyEnum)..High(TThirdPartyEnum) + eDefault;

  TMyEnum = (
    Low(TThirdPartyEnum)..High(TThirdPartyEnum),
    eDefault
  );
```

Is there a syntax which the compiler can understand?

Comment: AFAIK, enums are not inheritable (not exactly, what you are trying, but worth mentioning)

Comment: Just curious why not use `Low(TThirdPartyEnum)..High(TThirdPartyEnum),` instead of `eA..High(TThirdPartyEnum),`. What if `eA` got removed from the third party enum.

Comment: or moved to a higher place?  like `(e0, e1, eA, eB, eC)`

Comment: @NasreddineGalfout: you're right, I've updated the question

Comment: Placing the default value as the last member of enum doesn't seem to be the best idea for various reasons. One for all is that `Default(TMyEnum)` returns the member that is equal to zero, likely the first member of enum, not `eDefault`. Maybe you can solve your problem with generics - [Nullable<T>](https://spring4d.4delphi.com/docs/master/Html/index.htm?Spring.Nullable(T).htm). See also [this C# question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54561566/how-to-deal-with-enumeration-0-in-c-sharp-ca1008-discussion) and great answer by Eric Lippert regarding default enum values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot extend a enumerated type.

You will need a different approach to your problem, perhaps by declaring a new enumerated type and writing helper methods to map between them. You can use implicit cast operators of record helpers to make the code more readable, but that may be more complexity than the task justifies.