# Is it possible in Delphi to union enumerations into a larger enumeration?

Tags: delphi, enums, delphi-xe6

Delphi can have enumerated types, [e.g.:](http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/Article.asp?Name=Sets)

```
type
   TDay = (Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri, Sat, Sun);   // Enumeration values
```

Is it possible to *union* enumerated types:

```
type
   TWeekDay    = (Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri);
   TWeekendDay = (Sat, Sun);
   TDay        = (TWeekday, TWeekendDay);    //hypothetical syntax
```

In reality, i need to *decompose* a large list into the disjoint items they actually are, without breaking source-code compatibility:

```
type
   TWeekDay =    (Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri);
   TWeekendDay = (Sat, Sun);
   TDay =        (Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri, Sat, Sun); //identifier redeclared syntax error
```

And then change some variables:

- `Day: TWeekday;`<strike>`TDay;`</strike>
- `Day: TWeekendDay;`<strike>`TDay`</strike>

It's sort of the moral equivalent of [strict typing.](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130124-00/?p=5453)

Comment: Best I can think of is to use enumeration subranges instead. `TDay =  (Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri, Sat, Sun); TWeekDay =  Mon..Fri; TWeekendDay = Sat..Sun;`

Comment: @LURD, good idea. And most probably the only way to do this.

Comment: @LURD: I considered that (and actually wrote the comment), but then realized that it was most likely not going to work. Most weeks start with Sunday and end with Saturday, so the type should run in that order, which breaks `TWeekendDay` because you couldn't use `Sunday..Saturday` as a subrange.

Comment: @KenWhite beginning of the week depends on where you are from or for which part of the world/country this needs to make sense. As far as I know, most european countries view monday as the first day of the week

Comment: @Ancaron: Certainly it does. I never said it wouldn't. I pointed out that it might not work in all cases because of the issue of when a week begins and ends.

Comment: @KenWhite My comment was not meant as criticism. Just as an addition, because it might still work for him. :)

Comment: @Ancaron, true, but then the OP could not use a declared enumeration rather than a variable. Maybe it's not the best example used, but the principle of the question is quite clear ;-)

Comment: See also [this interesting question regarding C# enums](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54561566/how-to-deal-with-enumeration-0-in-c-sharp-ca1008-discussion) and alternative point of view in Eric Lippert's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is *"No"*.

But a workaround available to you, *if subrages are contiguous*, is to use subranges:

```
TDay = (Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri, Sat, Sun); 

TWeekDay2 = Mon..Fri; 
TWeekday = type TWeekDay2;

TWeekendDay2 = Sat..Sun;
TWeekendDay = type TWeekendDay;
```